# How to print the even numbers out of any random number in Java

Tags: java

I am looking for how to do the following.

I am looking to have a method accept a parameter of any number and have the method return the even numbers that were in the number that was the parameter. So if my number was "1234", the method would return the value `24`, by removing the odd numbers (1 and 3), or pulling out the even numbers (2 and 4).

Here is what I want my main method to look like:

```
System.out.println("testing removeOdds: 123456 = " + removeOdds(123456)); // Returns 246
System.out.println("testing removeOdds: 24680 = " + removeOdds(24680));  // Returns 24680
System.out.println("testing removeOdds: 13579 = " + removeOdds(13579)); // Returns 0
```

I don't want to use a while loop or a string to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You will need

- a loop (preferably a **while** loop)
- the division operator (`/`)
- the modulo operator (`%`)
- a Java compiler

#### EDIT:

Assume your number is "n" = 1234
now `n % 10` gives you 4.
`n / 10 = 123`.
Now if you do `n % 10`, you get 3.

So, put everything in a while loop with condition `n > 0` do `n % 10` then do `n % 2`. Take the value of `n % 2` out and print it.

#### Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 123435644;
    while (n > 0) {
        int val = n % 10;
        if (val % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(val);
        }
        n = n / 10;
    }
}
```

O/P:
4
4
6
4
2

Comment: how would i implement it?

Comment: I found some that could return the odd numbers, but not the even..

Comment: I understand how to do that. but say I a number what I need to do is pull out the even numbers so say I have "1234" the answer would be 24, because it pulled out the 2 and the 4. Or instead of pulling the 4 and 4, I could remove the 1 and the 3.

Comment: @cubmesa96 - check the code.. And please try to code such things by yourself.. :)